# Why is a pandas dataframe.query -> assign returning the original dataset size?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have been looking for an answer to this question for several hours. I am using python 3.6.7 and pandas 0.23.4. I am trying to get a subset of rows from a dataframe using query() and then add additional columns to that subset. Below is a snippet of the code:

```
df.query(f'({column}_c != {column}_c) & ({column}_t == {column}_t)')
                       .assign(reason='Calculated has value but target does not',
                               name=column,
                               calced=df[column + '_c'],
                               targeted=df[column + '_t'])
```

The original dataframe as about 29K rows, when I run just the query portion of this chain, I get 0 rows back. However, after the assign(), I have 29K rows again. I thought query() made a copy of the dataframe, so I would not expect this behavior. Anyone have any ideas what is going on (I have tried the df[] approach as well with the same results)

Comment: Your query returns an empty DataFrame and you assign a (couple of) new columns to that empty DataFrame using your original DataFrame so you have the same number of rows at the end. This is not about assign. This is about the new column you added (for example `df[column + '_c']`. This refers to the original DataFrame, not the newly created empty one.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the 'df' reference in the assign() is the original dataframe. It will cause the construction of a row for every row in the original dataframe. The way around this is to assign the filtered dataframe to a temporary variable and use that for the assign().